# Trig equations solution

Tags: limits

Solving the following for x:

$$
\frac{3\cos(2x)+5\cos(x)-1}{\sqrt{-\cot(x)}}=0
$$

The solution says that the answer is $x=-\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi k$ where $k$ is an integer.
I am not sure why there is the minus sign in front. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there is a domain issue with the function on the left-hand side of the equation, since the denominator is undefined wherever $ \ \cot x \ \ge \ 0 \ . $  Since the tangent function is positive in the first and third quadrants, so is the cotangent function; also, $ \ \cot x \ = \ 0 \ $ wherever $ \ \cos x \ = \  0 $ and undefined where $ \ \sin x \ = \  0 $ .    Putting this all together tells us that there are *only* solutions to the equation for  $ \ (\frac{2n-1}{2}) \cdot \pi \ < \ x \ < \ n \cdot \pi \ , $ the second and fourth quadrants without their boundaries.

The numerator is zero for

$$ \ 3 \ \cos(2x) \ + \ 5  \cos x \ - \ 1 \ = \ 3 \ (2 \cos^2 x \ - \ 1 ) + \ 5  \cos x \ - \ 1   $$

$$ = \ 6 \cos^2 x \ + \ 5  \cos x \ - \ 4 \ = \ (3 \ \cos x \ + \ 4 ) \ \cdot \ ( 2 \ \cos x \ - \ 1) \ = \ 0 .  $$

The first factor is never zero, but the second one is for $ \ \cos x \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ \Rightarrow \ x \ = \ \pm \frac{\pi}{3}  +  2k\pi \ , $ as **Oliver** has said.  However, the $  + \frac{\pi}{3}  +  2k\pi \ $ "family" of solutions is barred since those are in the first quadrant.  Thus, the permissible family of solutions is  $  - \frac{\pi}{3}  +  2k\pi \ . $

Comment: It isn't undefined when cot(x) > 0, it just has a complex value, but that doesn't matter if the numerator is equal to 0 anyway.

Comment: Moreover $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\cot{x}}} = \sqrt{-\tan{x}}$, so surely any multiple of $\pi$ is also a solution?

Comment: _Perhaps_ a set of solutions overlooked by the original solver.  However, the function as written has the radical in the denominator, so it is not strictly the same function as one has by changing the radical to use the reciprocal function in the numerator (the _limits_ are the same).  In any event, I presumed **bart** was asking about why the solution family involved  $ \ - \frac{\pi}{3} \ . $

Comment: Thank you, I get it now! Also wasn't helping for some reason was looking at the wrong quadrants the whole time :/

Comment: This is a somewhat weird function because of that denominator function.  For fun, try graphing it!

Answer (score 1):

You're solving $\cos{x}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\tan{x} = 0$.

So $x = \pm\frac{\pi}{3} + 2\pi k$ and $x = n\pi$

Answer (score 0):

First $\sqrt{-\cot x} \neq 0$, then $-\cot x >0$, so $x\in A= ]\frac{\pi \;(2k+1)}{2},\pi(k+1)[\;\;\;\;\; \forall k\in \mathbb{Z}$. 
\begin{eqnarray}
3\cos 2x + 5\cos x -1 &=& 0\\
3(2\cos^{2}x-1)+5\cos x -1 &=&0\\
6\cos^{2}x+5\cos x -4&=&0\\
x_{1}=-\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi k&,& x_{2}=\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi k \text{$\;\; \forall k\in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{eqnarray}

Now $x_{1}\in A$ but $x_{2}\notin A$, so, the solution of equation is $x_{1}=-\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi k,\; \forall k\in \mathbb{Z}$